# How to resolve e.clvp.Init is not a function error from SharePoint list view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, gridview

I have a list view showing below error message whenever I am opening list view.

[image]

When I refresh the page, the list view will start working again.
Any thoughts why this is happening?

PS: It is a GridView view

Comment: This issue is for single list view or all views in the list?

Comment: Only for single list view that also which is a gridview. Tried to google this error, but there is no trail of e.clvp